# How do I write a custom generator function with python

Tags: python, generator

I have this

```
for A in [0, -0.25, 0.25, -0.5, 0.5, -0.75, 0.75, -1.0, 1.0, -1.25, 1.25, -1.5, 1.5, -1.75, 1.75, -2.0, 2.0, -2.25, 2.25, -2.5, 2.5, -2.75, 2.75, -3.0, 3.0, -3.25, 3.25, -3.5, 3.5, -3.75, 3.75, -4.0, 4.0, -4.25, 4.25, -4.5, 4.5, -4.75, 4.75, -5.0, 5.0]:
```

Is it possible to make it with generator function? I have now this:

```
def frange(start, stop, step=1.0):
    while start <= stop:
        yield start
        start += step
```

and use like this:

```
for error in self.frange(-2.5, 2.5, 0.25):
```

but its returns `[-2.5, 2.25, ... , 0 , 2.25, 2.5]` and for my program it's very hard to calculate. because I finding the value the near to zero, but I don't know how much combinations it could be.

I need go from zero and next value must be in minus and plus value.
like `[0, -0.25, 0.25...]`.

Comment: How do you plan to use the function? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need, start from zero, and after that check minus value and next plus value. Its program for calculate geometry. The step is 0.25. Because when i use `def frange(start, stop, step=1.0):
    while start <= stop:
        yield start
        start += step` its every time like `[-5,-4.75 ... 0 ... ,4.75, 5]`

Comment: Why does it have to be a lambda function and not an ordinary function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant a generator instead of a lambda:

```
def opposing_numbers(increment, maximum):
     yield 0
     value = increment
     while value <= maximum:
         yield -value
         yield value
         value += increment
```

Then call it as:

```
opposing_numbers(0.25, 5)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The numpy solution is also good, but this does not require a third party package.
But you don't have to wrap the call in a `list`. And you forgot a closing `)`.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid. I wrapped it in a list just to explicitly match OP's request and because I was originally going to print that out, but you're absolutely right. Better to just take it off. Then I don't have to close the parenthesis :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `numpy.arange()` function, and then sort the values by their absolute value:

```
answer = sorted(np.arange(-5, 5.25, 0.25), key=abs)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[0.0,
 -0.25,
 0.25,
 -0.5,
 0.5,
 ...,
 -4.5,
 4.5,
 -4.75,
 4.75,
 -5.0,
 5.0]
```

Comment: FWIW, `key=lambda x: abs(x)` can be shortened: `key=abs`.

Comment: Good point, updating....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[(i // 2) * 0.25 * (2*(i&1)- 1) for i in range(1,42)]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a cool one liner

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*zip([i /4.0 for i in range(10)], [-i/4.0 for i in range(9)])))
```

> [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, -0.5, 0.75, -0.75, 1.0, -1.0, 1.25, -1.25, 1.5, -1.5, 1.75, -1.75, 2.0, -2.0]